# How to keep comments in a ghostscript pdf conversion to png?

Tags: powershell, pdf, ghostscript

I am converting a page of a PDF to an image, and that is working fine, the issue I am having is that it is leaving out the comments or annotations on the PDF page.

When I use the TIFF format, it keeps them in, but when I output to a PNG it removes them.

How do I keep them in?

Here is the code I am using to convert the PDF:

```
function Convert-pdf {

    param (
        $PDF_Output, # Output path where converted PDF files will be stored
        $path_to_pdf,
        $PNG_Output  # Output path where the PNG files will be saved
    )

  #Path to your Ghostscript EXE
  $tool = 'C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.55.0\bin\gswin64c.exe'
  $pdf = get-item $path_to_pdf
  $png = $PNG_Output + $pdf.BaseName + "%03d" + ".png"

  if(test-path $png)
  {
      "png file already exists " + $png
  }
  else
  {
      'Processing ' + $pdf.Name
      $param = "-sOutputFile=$png"
      & $tool -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png256 $param -r300 $pdf.FullName -c quit
  }
  Move-Item $pdf $PDF_Output
  return $png
}
```

When I change `png256` to `tiff64nc` it will show the annotations on the PDF, otherwise it does not show them.

Edit: I am using GS version 9.55.0

Here is an example image, of the pdf I am putting through the code:

[image: testPdf.pdf]

And here is the output that I get:

[image: testOutput.png]

If you want to test for yourself, here is the file:

[Link to PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10NL1KJ0RvXkplxc1Lt26EUZyBAI7O7Ts/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You haven't said which version of GS you are using, and you haven't supplied the back channel transcript, nor have you supplied an example file to try. When I try the current HEAD from the GS Git repository using "gs -sDEVICE=png256 -o out.png -dFirstPage=2 -dLastPage=2 /ghostpdl/examples/annots.pdf" the annotations are correctly rendered.

Comment: Apologies for that. I will edit the post as well, but I am using GS version 9.55.0 -- as for an example, let me get something together for that. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @KenS I have provided the version, sample images, and a link to the pdf in the post.

Comment: Well I'm certainly getting your second wrong result, with very nearly every device. The 64-bit (4x16-bit channels) does work which is plain weird. I'd suggest opening a bug report. I'm going to guess (and that's all it is) that the ExtGState with a CA value of 255 is the problem. Valid values are 0 to 1 I believe. And indeed, if I change that to be 1 instead, then the annotations render. Note that Acrobat often ignores appearance streams and regenerates them while GS honours them.

Comment: I submitted a bug report to them. Will update here when they respond to it.

Comment: FWIW the PDF Reference, 1.7 edition (it's free and easier to use than the ISO spec which costs money), page 527 paragraph near the ends says 'All of these shape and opacity inputs range in value from 0.0 to 1.0, with a default value of 1.0.". The file has been edited after creation, the creation tool apparently was Acrobat Distiller, don't know what modified it, but I would guess its that which created the anntations and the duff constant alpha values.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The bug report came back and it seems that the ExtGState being 255 is the problem. But it isn't a bug on their end, which means I will have to handle this differently. I think it may be an issue with the annotation program that is being used to add those bubbles to the PDF. Unfortunately I have no control of that end of the process. So I will have to find another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your question you have discovered that Artifex GhostScript does not print those annotations, however they are viewable in Artifex MuPDF.

So oddly you can convert the pdf file via Artifex Mutool. The quickest way is to convert direct to PNG:-

```
mutool convert -O resolution=300,colorspace=rgb -o output-rgb.png "69846382 annots not printing in GS png.pdf"
```

Note the colorspace=rgb is not restricted to 256 colours. In your case, with or without that option, the output of the source 5 colours is dependant on other factors but defaults for your file to 1238 AA colours.

We can get similar if not identical results using the shorter draw command

```
mutool draw -o output-rgb.png  -r 300 -c rgb "69846382 annots not printing in GS png.pdf"
```

I tried dozens of options to use mutool to rebuild the pdf in a pdf format that GS would use to output 256 colors (and the annotations) but with varied success, (though I got some nice alternatives  like SVG). You could try a  different conversion route and options but the results here seem to be fairly similar.

IF you really need 256 colours you could backfeed the png into a pdf then submit that to GS so we get your desired 256 max colours (in this case its 101 colors) but see later a shorter option.

[image]

**So** in total to get 256 max colours you need 3 lines using your shell path\variables and beware multipage %d values.

```
mutool draw -o "out-draw.png"  -r 300 "69846382 annots not printing in GS png.pdf"
mutool draw -o "out-draw.pdf"  "out-draw.png"
gswin64c -o "GSout256.png" -sDEVICE=png256 -r300 "out-draw.pdf"
```

**And** since the common format handling is akin to PS graphics using that in two steps gave a much faster result.

```
mutool draw -o "out-draw.ps" -r 300 "69846382 annots not printing in GS png.pdf"
gswin64c -o "GSout256.png" -sDEVICE=png256 -r300 "out-draw.ps"
```

However the result of double image in-out processes was "Moire" than desired  [image] , which I should have expected. Whichever method I used to improve the result it was not an even tone [image] thus I suspect even if the annotations were good the result would not equal expectation, that is not just Ghostscript, I get similar results saving as 256 colour output from MSpaint
etc. in effect its colour "dithering".

Also I tried without success to pipe one into another since GS should input piped data, and MuTool can output to pipe, but hit problems, most probably due to me corrupting GS by testing different calls (beware accidentally overwriting the exe) I dropped trying, as we see, it seemed not worth chasing in this case.

Finally with my trials for the **safest** shortest command we are currently left with mutool 1023 colours that would need another command line tool to drop those to 8 bit per pixel colours. [image]

```
mutool draw -o"out.png" -r 300 "69846382 annots not printing in GS png.pdf"
irfanview / gimp / other image converter
```

The alternative is to use a graphics package that can read pdf and output 8 bpp without dithering for a result much like this **try right click to download** [image]

Comment: This was very helpful thank you. This worked for what I needed, and I didn't have to go digging for another solution elsewhere. Very much appreciate your help.